# Springboot date entity problem "Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date'

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, hibernate, parameters

When I tried to get with these url : http://www.localhost:8080/api/employee/search?startDate=2000-10-22&salary=10000

This error message shows up : "Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam java.util.Date] for value '2000-10-22'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException"

Params : startDate = 2000-10-22 salary = 10000

What is the problem here ?

Employee Class :

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @NotBlank
    private String nationalId;

    @NotBlank
    private String name;

    @NotBlank
    private String surname;

    private Integer salary;

    @JoinColumn(name="start_date")
    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date startDate;

    private String office;

    private String department;
```

Query in my repository :

```
  @Query("Select e FROM Employee e  " +
            "where " +
            " (:startDate is NULL or e.startDate > :startDate) " +
            " AND " +
            " (:salary is NULL or e.salary > :salary) ")
    List<Employee> searchEmployees(Date startDate,Integer salary);
```

ServiceImpl:

```
 @Override
    public List<Employee> searchEmployees(Date startDate,Integer salary){
        List <Employee> employees = employeeRepository.searchEmployees(startDate,salary);
        return employees;
    }
```

Controller :

```
@GetMapping(path="/search")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Employee>> searchEmployees(@RequestParam("startDate") Date startDate,
                                                          @RequestParam("salary") Integer salary){
        return ResponseEntity.ok(employeeService.searchEmployees(startDate,salary));
    }
```

Comment: The link you provided is a localhost link. So I hope you understand that it can't be seen by anyone.

Comment: Yes,that is the url that after after I put the params on postman. I wrote that for if I made a mistake there

Answer (score 3):

This is because by default, Spring cannot convert String parameters to any date or time object.

Use this instead.

`@RequestParam @DateTimeFormat(pattern= "yyyy-MM-dd") Date startDate`

Answer (score 0):

problem is java convert string to date
you can try this

```
@GetMapping(path="/search")
public ResponseEntity<List<Employee>> searchEmployees(@RequestParam("startDate") @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) Date startDate,
                                                      @RequestParam("salary") Integer salary){
    return ResponseEntity.ok(employeeService.searchEmployees(startDate,salary));
}
```

Comment: With that I get this error "org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not determine data type of parameter $1"